# Why doesn't `std::forward_list::insert_after` return the first element inserted as other sequence containers?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't `std::forward_list::insert_after` return the ***first*** inserted element as other sequence containers such as `list` and `vector`. Are there any deliberate reasons?

Answer (score 3):

`forward_list` is very different from other sequences, as is `insert_after`. In order to return the first inserted item it would have to use extra time and space to save off that element, while the *last* element will be available as part of the insertion algorithm. Not only that, but returning an iterator to the first element inserted from a range would give you an iterator you could use to insert into the middle of the range you just added, while an iterator to the end of the range lets you append additional data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the committee's reasoning, but here's mine:

You can insert multiple elements, e.g. a "range". See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/insert_after

Returning the first element wouldn't be really valuable, as getting to the first element is trivial - you already have an iterator after which it was inserted.

OTOH, getting to the last inserted element might be costly, if you've inserted a lot of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

After considering for some time, here is my understanding.

## 1. Normal sequence containers

For normal sequence containers, `insert` gets an iterator (which I'll call `itl`) as parameter, and inserts elements before `itl`.  Then returns the iterator (`itf`) that points to the first inserted element.  Now you have 2 iterators separately denoting the range (first and off-the-end) of the  inserted elements.

```
elem-elem-inserted-inserted-inserted-elem-elem
             |                        |
           (itf)                    (itl)
```

However, `insert` operation may invalidate `itl`, so we need to consider the following two situations:

### 1.1 Linked structure

For linked structure, `itl` remains valid.  Therefore (`itf`,`itl`) forms a valid range for inserted elements.

### 1.2 Contiguous structure

For contiguous structure, `itl` are invalidated after insertion. However such structures usually support random access, so it's still relatively easy to get an `itl` through simple arithmetic on `itf`. On the other hand, returning an iterator to the first inserted element preserves consistency.

## 2. Forward-list

`insert_after` for `forward-list` gets an iterator (`itf`) as parameter, and inserts elements after it. Then it returns an iterator to the last inserted element (`itl`).  Because `itf` remains valid, we have a similar range again.

```
elem-elem-inserted-inserted-inserted-elem-elem
      |                        |
    (itf)                    (itl)
```

## 3. Conclusion

No matter whether `insert` operation returns a iterator to the first inserted element or to the last inserted element, it always tries to provide access to the beginning and end of inserted elements at the same time, which provides maximum flexibility.